# Adding array as object value based on duplicate in column

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

So, let's say the table I'm looping thorugh is looking like this:

[image]

Each unique value in the second column should be an object and where
one of the keys should contain all values on the corresponding rows.
Something like this:

```
skillMatrix[0]: {val: 2, agents: ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'}
```

This is as far as I come, I'm stuck..

```
    for (i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
        skillMatrix[i] = {}
    }

$.ajax(getSkills).done(function (res) {

                var sg;

    $(res).find('td:nth-child(3)').each(function(){

                a = $(this).parent().find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
                a = a.split('.');

                if(a[1] == '') {
                first = a[3];
                last = a[2];
                }
                else {
                first = a[2];
                last = a[1];
                }
                reJoin = last + ' ' + first;

                var sg = $(this);
                sg = sg.text().split('_');
                sg = sg[3];

                for (i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
                    if (q[i] == sg) {
                    skillMatrix[i].group = sg;
                    skillMatrix[i].ag = reJoin;
                    }
                }
    })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should collect the unique value of each row, you could do it by selecting each row & add the text of the second column if it's not in the array that will contain all these unique values. This code will solve this problem:

```
var arr=[];
    $("tr").each(function(){
      if(!arr.includes($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text())){
        arr.push($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text());
      }
    })
```

Then select foreach of this values the `td` that contains the `i-th` value of the declared array `arr`: `$("tr td:nth-child(2):contains("+arr[i]+")")`.

After that foreach selected elements, get its parent then search for the first colum that contains the agent: `$(this).parent().find("td:eq(0)").text()`.

Combain all these in an *Js* `object`, these will give the following demo:

```js
var arr=[];
  
$("tr").each(function(){
  if(!arr.includes($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text())){
    arr.push($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text());
  }
})
  var obj={};
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
var agents=[];
$("tr td:nth-child(2):contains("+arr[i]+")").each(function(){

agents.push($(this).parent().find("td:eq(0)").text());
  

});

obj[i]= {val: arr[i], agents:agents};
}

console.log(obj);
```

```css
td{
border:solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>value 1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>value 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>value 3</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>value 4</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```